# access _cat/indices information using query string query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

When you run either `curl http://<node_ip>:9200/_cat/indices` or `GET _cat/indices` (the latter one in the **Dev Tools console**, you get a summary of all the indices present in your cluster, as well as some size and counts statistics.

Is there a way to access that information via [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)?

I mean, is there an internal ES index with all that information available, that I can query to get the same/similar information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. That information is not kept in an index, but in the cluster state which is stored in a different location.